# Input.session with GMT

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to create a input that I can change the UTC I'm in, so when I change the UTC in this input the session will update to the new hour, I don't know how to do that with this script using `input.session` and the `timerange`, `open_bar` and `is_open` function. Please anyone give me a tip.
(creator of the script: RobMinty on TradingView)

```
//@version=5
indicator('FXN - Asian Session Range', shorttitle='Asian Session Range', overlay=true)

// Sessão asiática ocorre das 20h até a meia-noite
i_sess1 = input.session('2000-0001', 'Time', group='g01')

show_asian_session = input(defval=true, title='Show Asian Session Box')

isValidResolution() =>
    timeframe.isdwm == true or timeframe.period == '120' or timeframe.period == '240' or timeframe.period == '180' or timeframe.period == '360' ? 0 : 1

timerange(res, sess) =>
    not na(time(res, sess)) ? 1 : 0

// Define a sessão asiática
asian_session = i_sess1

open_bar(ses) => 
    t = time("D", ses) 
    na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

is_open(ses) =>
    not na(time(timeframe.period, ses))

asian_open_bar = open_bar(asian_session)
asian_is_open = is_open(asian_session)
asian_low = float(na)
asian_low := asian_is_open ? asian_open_bar ? low : math.min(asian_low[1], low) : asian_low[1]
asian_high = float(na)
asian_high := asian_is_open ? asian_open_bar ? high : math.max(asian_high[1], high) : asian_high[1]
asian_mid = math.avg(asian_low, asian_high)

//Plot Statements For Opening Range Lines
asianOpenRangeHigh = plot(timerange(timeframe.period, asian_session) > 0 and show_asian_session and isValidResolution() ? asian_high : na, color=color.blue, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1,  show_last=5, editable=false)
asianOpenRangeLow = plot(timerange(timeframe.period, asian_session) > 0 and show_asian_session and isValidResolution() ? asian_low : na, color=color.blue, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1,  show_last=5, editable=false)
fill(asianOpenRangeHigh, asianOpenRangeLow, color=show_asian_session and isValidResolution() ? color.new(color.blue, 90) : na, title="Fill Asian Range Color")
```

I tried this: (but didn't work)

```
//@version=5
indicator('FXN - Asian Session Range', shorttitle='Asian Session Range', overlay=true)

// Sessão asiática ocorre das 20h até a meia-noite
i_sess1 = input.session('2000-0001', 'Time', group='g01')

show_asian_session = input(defval=true, title='Show Asian Session Box')

isValidResolution() =>
    timeframe.isdwm == true or timeframe.period == '120' or timeframe.period == '240' or timeframe.period == '180' or timeframe.period == '360' ? 0 : 1

timerange(res, sess) =>
    not na(time(res, sess)) ? 1 : 0

open_bar(ses) => 
    t = time("D", ses) 
    na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

is_open(ses) =>
    not na(time(timeframe.period, ses))

i_tz = input.int(-5, title = 'GMT', minval = -12, maxval = +12, group='g01')

string utcStr   = ''
if i_tz > 0
    utcStr      := 'UTC+' + str.tostring(i_tz)
if i_tz <= 0
    utcStr      := 'UTC' + str.tostring(i_tz)

i_tzz = str.tostring(i_tz, format.price)

string tz = (i_tzz == 'No' or i_tzz == '') ? na : i_tzz
int sess1 = time(timeframe.period, i_sess1, utcStr)

// Define a sessão asiática
asian_session = sess1

asian_open_bar = open_bar(asian_session)
asian_is_open = is_open(asian_session)
asian_low = float(na)
asian_low := asian_is_open ? asian_open_bar ? low : math.min(asian_low[1], low) : asian_low[1]
asian_high = float(na)
asian_high := asian_is_open ? asian_open_bar ? high : math.max(asian_high[1], high) : asian_high[1]
asian_mid = math.avg(asian_low, asian_high)

//Plot Statements For Opening Range Lines
asianOpenRangeHigh = plot(timerange(timeframe.period, asian_session) > 0 and show_asian_session and isValidResolution() ? asian_high : na, color=color.blue, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1,  show_last=5, editable=false)
asianOpenRangeLow = plot(timerange(timeframe.period, asian_session) > 0 and show_asian_session and isValidResolution() ? asian_low : na, color=color.blue, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1,  show_last=5, editable=false)
fill(asianOpenRangeHigh, asianOpenRangeLow, color=show_asian_session and isValidResolution() ? color.new(color.blue, 90) : na, title="Fill Asian Range Color")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define one user input with all the possiblities:

```
in_time_tz = input.string('GMT-8', title='Timezone', options=['GMT-11', 'GMT-10', 'GMT-9', 'GMT-8', 'GMT-7', 'GMT-6', 'GMT-5', 'GMT-4', 'GMT-3', 'GMT-2', 'GMT-1', 'GMT', 'GMT+1', 'GMT+2', 'GMT+3', 'GMT+330', 'GMT+4', 'GMT+430', 'GMT+5', 'GMT+530', 'GMT+6', 'GMT+7', 'GMT+8', 'GMT+9', 'GMT+10', 'GMT+11', 'GMT+12'])
```

Then pass this to any `time()` function as its third `timezone` argument. There are three in this particular script you shared.

```
time(timeframe, session, timezone) → series int
```

This will do it:

```
//@version=5
indicator('FXN - Asian Session Range', shorttitle='Asian Session Range', overlay=true)

// Sessão asiática ocorre das 20h até a meia-noite
in_time_tz = input.string('GMT-8', title='Timezone', options=['GMT-11', 'GMT-10', 'GMT-9', 'GMT-8', 'GMT-7', 'GMT-6', 'GMT-5', 'GMT-4', 'GMT-3', 'GMT-2', 'GMT-1', 'GMT', 'GMT+1', 'GMT+2', 'GMT+3', 'GMT+330', 'GMT+4', 'GMT+430', 'GMT+5', 'GMT+530', 'GMT+6', 'GMT+7', 'GMT+8', 'GMT+9', 'GMT+10', 'GMT+11', 'GMT+12'])
i_sess1 = input.session('2000-0001', 'Time', group='g01')

show_asian_session = input(defval=true, title='Show Asian Session Box')

isValidResolution() =>
    timeframe.isdwm == true or timeframe.period == '120' or timeframe.period == '240' or timeframe.period == '180' or timeframe.period == '360' ? 0 : 1

timerange(res, sess) =>
    not na(time(res, sess, in_time_tz)) ? 1 : 0

// Define a sessão asiática
asian_session = i_sess1

open_bar(ses) => 
    t = time("D", ses, in_time_tz) 
    na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

is_open(ses) =>
    not na(time(timeframe.period, ses, in_time_tz))

asian_open_bar = open_bar(asian_session)
asian_is_open = is_open(asian_session)
asian_low = float(na)
asian_low := asian_is_open ? asian_open_bar ? low : math.min(asian_low[1], low) : asian_low[1]
asian_high = float(na)
asian_high := asian_is_open ? asian_open_bar ? high : math.max(asian_high[1], high) : asian_high[1]
asian_mid = math.avg(asian_low, asian_high)

//Plot Statements For Opening Range Lines
asianOpenRangeHigh = plot(timerange(timeframe.period, asian_session) > 0 and show_asian_session and isValidResolution() ? asian_high : na, color=color.blue, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1,  show_last=5, editable=false)
asianOpenRangeLow = plot(timerange(timeframe.period, asian_session) > 0 and show_asian_session and isValidResolution() ? asian_low : na, color=color.blue, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1,  show_last=5, editable=false)
fill(asianOpenRangeHigh, asianOpenRangeLow, color=show_asian_session and isValidResolution() ? color.new(color.blue, 90) : na, title="Fill Asian Range Color")
```